# Redirect header php to success page

Tags: php

I have a contact contact form that after submitting a message, if it is sucess it should go to the success.php page, but im having a issue, i want this page only be available when the user is redirect from the sendForm.php. How should i make this permission in my script?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

Many ways simplest way is to send parameter in URL ex. `success.php?ok=1`

```
<form action="success.php?ok=1"  ...>
```

And at top of `success.php` page  write:

```
<?php if( isset($_GET['ok']) ){
 ?>

 html page code here

<?php }else{

 //code if not redirect from sendForm.php

 ?>
```

or send POST request to look more professional without annoying url parameters and use `isset($_POST['ok'])`.

Comment: The sendForm.php is in a separate file, is independent, it doesnt mix with html, one send the email and than redirect.

Comment: No problem you want `success.php` page only be available when the user is redirect from the sendForm.php so redirect user from sendForm.php to 'success.php?ok=1' and add code above.